# Concerns about a dice-pool system

Tags: dice, statistics, indie-rpg

I'm writing "yet another rpg system" and I'm choosing a way to determine success.
I'd like a dice pool mechanic, and I've come up with this.

PCs have *characteristics* and *abilities*.

- **Char. Mods** will go from **1 to 10** (char/5, max char is 50).
- **Abilities** will go from **0 to 5** (or 10, still deciding).

PCs can perform actions *against an opponent* (attack, cast a spell) or *againsts a difficulty level* (jump, picklock), which is the number of successful dice. Actions have a **Success**, a **Critical Success** and a **Failure**.

The result of a roll is decided by throwing `Nd6`, with `N = Mod. Char. + Ability` (so it will be 1->15/20).
A die is:

- successful (SD) with **4-5-6**
- unsuccessful with **1-2-3**.

With 1 you lose a SD, with 6 you can roll an additional one (so this is *open-ended*).

- *Roll against an opponent*: both PCs roll their dice (attacking move
  vs defensive move), the one with more SD wins, if the difference is >3, it is a critical success.
- *Roll against a difficulty level*: PC rolls its dice, if SD = DL he
  succeed, if the difference is >3, it is a critical success.

I've read tons of threads on dice rolling and I'm understanding I can't understand all the nuances of statistics, so I'm asking you:

1. What do you think about this system?
2. Are there edge cases to consider?
3. Have you used it before? how it went?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is plenty of rolling here, that's for sure. Exploding 6s are fairly common, what concerns me is 1s. Having a punishing mechanic like this would make sense if there was an element of risk-taking: if players could choose to roll extra dice but risk them negating the successes they already have. As it stands, rolling a 1 simply negates a success, meaning you may as well not have rolled those two and gotten the same result. It's not *fun*. Especially if you rolled 1s as a result of exploding 6s, turning a bonus roll into a penalty.

I'd advise looking for a different meaning to 1s, if you wish to use them. For instance, consider Don't Rest Your Head. In it, you roll different-colored dice representing Discipline, Exhaustion and Madness, all of which give your character strength. While you simply add up all 1-3 results which are successes, you also care about which color got the highest value, as that pool *dominates*, both affecting the tone of the scene and having further mechanical effects. So perhaps 1s are complications that arise, and players can buy them off with successes. Each 1 is a "yes, but" you get to insert into the situation. Now it's a choice to be made and therefore interesting.

As for loopholes, there aren't really any. It's a simple enough dice pool mechanic, the more dice you roll the better (even if you could be disadvantaged by multiple 1s, it's much more likely you'll benefit from extra dice).

In conclusion: the mechanic is complex for the sake of complexity. There is never a choice to be made here: you always want to roll all the dice you can get. And once a player rolls them, its out of their hands. Exploding dice add excitement while negative dice just add busywork. Either get rid of negative dice or change them.

Comment: I see the problem with 1s now. The higher my dice count, the higher the risk to lose a success. I'll think about this one.
About exploding 6s, I got a suggestion to just make the 6s count as 2 successes, less dice to roll, no 1s in the way.